# How to numerically solve Fredholm equation of the first kind using Tikhonov regularization method?

Tags: numerical-methods, integral-equations, regularization

I am tasked to write a program that solves Fredholm equation of the first kind using Tikhonov regularization method. So far, unfortunately, I've only found the general form of Fredholm equation of the first kind:
$$\int_a^bK(x, s)u(s)ds = f(x)$$
Where $K$ and $f$ are supposed to be known and we must find $u$. Everything else seemed to be way beyond my understanding and generally not helpful for writing an algorithm.

As an example I am using the following equation:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}cos(x + s)u(s)ds = \pi cos (x)$$
where $u(s)=cos (s)$

Comment: I don't have specific experience, but I'd discretize the support of $K$ obtaining a matrix $\hat{K}$ with the values of $K$ on the discrete points. Then you can write a system of equations that represent the integral, something like $\hat{K}\Delta s\hat{u}=\hat{f}$ that you can solve with the regularisation of the L2 norm of $\hat{u}$. $\Delta s $ is the discretisation step over the $s$ axis.